# variables are not interpreted when I use the "cat" command to put the contents of a text file into a variable

Tags: bash, variables, cat

I need some help please, I have a script (script.sh) that content:

```
#!/bin/bash

export name='toto'
file='file.txt'
content=$(cat "file.txt")
echo "$content"
```

file.txt content some text :
I am $name

now when I run my script (script.sh) the variable $name is not interpreted and I got a result like this :
I am $name
And I want to have a result like : I am toto

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548559/substitute-variable-inside-another-variable-in-shell-script-without-reassignment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `envsubst` for this:

```
content=$(envsubst < "file.txt")
```

Comment: This good answer would be even better without the [UUOC](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).